# How to let users send private messages to their friends without a link?

Tags: facebook, dialog, message, send

I'm adding a private messaging system to my app,
so users could send private message to their friends.

I thought I could use the [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), but the **link** param seems to be required.

Is there any reason to require that property ?
Is there any other way to send private messages ? (Except XMPP Chat)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those are your two only options (send dialog and chat api).

You can also let one user write on the other users wall and set the privacy so that only they can view the message, but that is not really what you're after from what I understand (neither is the chat api btw, since it works only if the two users are online at the time).

I found this thread which talks about it in length: [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)